# How to embed JButton to JavaFX pane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add JButton to a specific pane using my JavaFX controller class.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Pane pane;

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
                 }
             });
         }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);


             pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to mix javaFx and Swing?

Comment: Why not use a [JavaFX button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html)?

Comment: I'm eventually going to use it for network graph visualization using JUNG which I'm still new to. At the moment it would seem I can only add that to Swing components

Comment: What *is* wrong? Is the button not being added to the right pane? Is the button not being added at all?

Comment: @PotatoMash Looks [this quick tutorial on using JavaFX with JUNG](http://blog.jeffreyguenther.com/post/61616273121/exploring-the-possibility-of-graph-layouts-in) might be useful to you... Also check out [this article](http://www.timheng.com/udgl.html) and [this github repo](https://gist.github.com/jrguenther/9d0c37329f9928a2b56e)

Comment: My guess is that your error is in code that you don't show.

Comment: @PotatoMash even if you are required to implement the graphs in Swing you are still able to make all UI controls in JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of adding a Swing JButton to a JavaFX pane in the Oracle documentation on [Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm).  The following example is just a copy and paste from there (with a slight update to use Java 8 features).

[image: swinginfx]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start (Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        createSwingContent(swingNode);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 250, 150));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!")));
    }
}
```

Of course this is a toy sample and most people would just use a JavaFX button instead.  For more complex examples where you are dealing with a large existing code base written against the existing Swing library, rather than a solitary button, the approach above may make sense, though there still may be residual issues like inconsistent look and feel and additional complexity in ensuring that threading rules between disparate UI toolkits are not validated, etc.